DearByGui и латышские символы
Не могу “заставить” DearPyGUI принимать в add_input_text латышские символы.
with dpg.font_registry():
    with dpg.font(f'C:/Windows/Fonts/Arial.ttf', 15, default_font=True, id="Default font"):
        dpg.add_font_range_hint(dpg.mvFontRangeHint_Default)
        dpg.add_font_range(0x100, 0x17E)
        dpg.add_font_chars([0x0100,0x0101,
                            0x010C,0x010D,
                            0x0112,0x0113,
                            0x0122,0x0123,
                            0x012A,0x012B,
                            0x0136,0x0137,
                            0x013B,0x013C,
                            0x0145,0x0146,
                            0x0160,0x0161,
                            0x016A,0x016B,
                            0x017D,0x017E,
                            ])
        dpg.add_char_remap(...................)
    dpg.bind_font("default_font")

Диапазон uni-кодов указал; сами символы указал. Далее следует использовать add_char_remap,
но вот что на что менять понятия не имею.
Буду признателен за помощь.

Задачу решил “в лоб”.
Получилось, наверное, не совсем элегантно, но работает.
Клавиатура в режиме LV. При нажатом правом Alt-е нажимал нужную мне клавишу. Получал изображение некоего символа, искал его в таблице unicodе-ов и заменял на нужный мне.
получилось вот такое:
dpg.add_font_chars([0x100,0x101,    # Ā ā
                    0x10C,0x10D,    # Č č
                    0x112,0x113,    # Ē ē
                    0x122,0x123,    # Ģ ģ
                    0x12A,0x12B,    # Ī ī
                    0x136,0x137,    # Ķ ķ
                    0x13B,0x13C,    # Ļ ļ
                    0x145,0x146,    # Ņ ņ
                    0x160,0x161,    # Š š
                    0x16A,0x16B,    # Ū ū
                    0x17D,0x17E,    # Ž ž
                    ])
dpg.add_char_remap(0x00C2, 0x0100)  # Ā
dpg.add_char_remap(0x00E2, 0x0101)  # ā
dpg.add_char_remap(0x00C8, 0x010C)  # Č
dpg.add_char_remap(0x00E8, 0x010D)  # č
dpg.add_char_remap(0x00C7, 0x0112)  # Ē
dpg.add_char_remap(0x00E7, 0x0101)  # ē
dpg.add_char_remap(0x00CC, 0x0122)  # Ģ
dpg.add_char_remap(0x00EC, 0x0123)  # ģ
dpg.add_char_remap(0x00CE, 0x012A)  # Ī
dpg.add_char_remap(0x00EE, 0x012B)  # ī
dpg.add_char_remap(0x00CD, 0x0136)  # Ķ
dpg.add_char_remap(0x00ED, 0x0137)  # ķ
dpg.add_char_remap(0x00CF, 0x013B)  # Ļ
dpg.add_char_remap(0x00EF, 0x013C)  # ļ
dpg.add_char_remap(0x00D2, 0x0145)  # Ņ
dpg.add_char_remap(0x00F2, 0x0146)  # ņ
dpg.add_char_remap(0x00D0, 0x0160)  # Š
dpg.add_char_remap(0x00F0, 0x0161)  # š
dpg.add_char_remap(0x00DB, 0x016A)  # Ū
dpg.add_char_remap(0x00FB, 0x016B)  # ū
dpg.add_char_remap(0x00DE, 0x017D)  # Ž
dpg.add_char_remap(0x00FE, 0x017E)  # ž

